# Help rearranging an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The original equation is
$V + X(dv/dx) = (v^2-4)/(1-v)$

I need to be able separate this so I can solve it (as an ODE)

The intermediate step is listed as $x^{-1} - {(1-v)/(v^2-4)} dv/dx = 0$

I'm not seeing the algebra here.

Comment: Are the $V$ and $X$ supposed to be in caps? If that $V$ wasn't there you could just divide the whole equation by $\frac {x\cdot (v^2-4)}{1-v}$. If it is there and they're lower case is the lhs just $\frac {\text {d}}{\text{dx}} (xv)$?

Answer (score 0):

If the capital $V,X$ are the same as small $v,x$, then simply take $v$ from LHS to RHS to obtain:

$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{2v^2-v-4}{1-v}$,
i.e. $\frac{(1-v)dv}{2v^2-v-4}=\frac{dx}{x}$

Now it is separated.